# AJAX JSON Cross-Origin Read Blocking

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to get my code working but no matter where or how i do my research i cannot find answer to my problem.

So here's the code:

I've tried to get help from different resources, stackoverflow, jquery documentation, json documentation, different google searches about Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)

JSON

```
{
    "events" : [
    {
        "id" : "1", 
        "name" : "100m"
    },

    {
        "id" : "2", 
        "name" : "Long Jump"
    },

    {
        "id" : "3", 
        "name" : "Shot Put"
    },

    {
        "id" : "4", 
        "name" : "High Jump"
    }

]
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <button id="getData">Events</button>
        <div id="eventList"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#getData").click(function () {
                var eventList = $("#eventList");
                var url = "events.json";
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    var events = data.events.map(function (item) {
                        return item.id + " (" + item.name + ")";
                    });
                    eventList.empty();
                    if (events.length) {
                        var content = "<li>" + events.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
                        var list = $("<ul>").html(content);
                        eventList.append(list);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I need my button to function using AJAX, but at the moment im stuck, when i press the button i get "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response" error.

Comment: are you trying to get events.json from local? If you want to test for local, you can define a variable in js file which will be your data that you will get from server in future. In $.getJSON you have to enter a valid server url to fetch data

Comment: No, im not on local but i've tested it on local but i didn't change the code, but can you provide me a link maybe how to get it working on server please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4dfp8a0t/ Open the fiddle and run and see the results in console. It's a open source api which gives json response and how I have used to fetch data using $.getJSON

Comment: Again is your json file served by web server?

Comment: Yes, it is served by web server

Answer (score 0):

Assume you send to the front-end that json structure.
Server Side : You can use php to add that structure to an array and then send it top the front end.

Server Side could be something like:

```
while("Loop through that file struture"){
  $output [] = array("id"=>$id,"name"=>$name);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Client side code:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "documentlink.php", /*Link to the file, I assume you are getting that returned from a php.*/
   type: "post", /*If it is post use, else no need to use just remove it*/
   data:data, /*This if you want to send any parameter with your request to the server*/
   success:function(data){
     var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
     myObj = JSON.parse(obj);
     $.each(myObj, function(i){
          var id = myObj[i].id;
          var name = myObj[i].name;

    });
  }
});
```